# Is a surjective linear transformation from an infinite dimensional vector space $X$ to $X$ always a one-one mapping?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Is a surjective linear transformation from an infinite dimensional vector space $X$ to $X$  always a one-one mapping?

(In case of finite dimensional, surjectivity implies one-one. What about infinite dimensional vector space?)

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1120329/linear-transformations-on-infinite-dimensional-vector-spaces?rq=1).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The standard counterexample to this is the **shift-left** map, on the space of infinite sequences of numbers:

$$ T(x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots) = (x_2,x_3,x_4,\ldots) $$

Answer (score 9):

No. The derivative on the space of polynomials is surjective but not injective.

Answer (score 0):

This has been already answered but let me remark that there exist spaces where this is actually true as long as by a *linear map* the OP means a *continuous linear map* on a *normed space*.

Then all [hereditarily indecomposable Banach spaces](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/74171/hereditarily-indecomposable-banach-spaces-and-separable-quotient-problem) have the property that surjectivity implies injectivity (all Fredholm operators acting on such spaces have index zero, hence surjective implies injective in this case).